# Extending array in vbscript function

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I found the [following VBscript function to generate a random code](https://givemeanthony.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/random-string-generator/) using Uppercase & Lowercase characters.
I'd like to extend it to include digits - I tried by adding in the extra few lines (max3 and min3)
, but am not sure how to change the Array to allow for the new variables.

```
Function GenerateRandomString(StrLen,upper,lower,numeric)
    Dim charCase
    ' ASCII: Lowercase Alpha Characters
    max=122
    min=97
    ' ASCII: Capital Alpha Characters
    max2=90
    min2=65

    //  THIS BELOW IS WHAT I ADDED:
    ' ASCII: numeric Characters
    max3=57
    min3=49
    // END ADD
    

    For i=0 To (StrLen-1)
        Randomize
        charCase = Array((max-min+1)*Rnd+min,(max2-min2+1)*Rnd+min2)   <!-- Not sure how to change this?
        myStr = myStr & Chr(int(charCase(int(Rnd*2))))
    Next
   
    GenerateRandomString = myStr
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code creates an array with 2 values then picks one of those. The simplest solution is to add a third value to the array:

```
Randomize
For i=0 To (StrLen-1)
    charCase = Array((max - min + 1) * Rnd + min, _
                     (max2 - min2 + 1) * Rnd + min2, _
                     (max3 - min3 + 1) * Rnd + min3)
    myStr = myStr & Chr(int(charCase(int(Rnd * 3))))
Next
```

Another option is to create a string with the values you want and use that:

```
letters ="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"
For i=0 To (StrLen-1)
    ' Pick a random letter from the string and add to the result
    myStr = myStr & Mid(letters, int(Rnd * Len(letters)) + 1, 1)
Next
```

Comment: Using your second option, I *sometimes* receive this error: `Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid'`  - referring to the line of `myStr = myStr & Mid(letters, int(Rnd * Len(letters)), 1)` . Any idea what that may be?

Comment: Sorry, `int(Rnd * Len(letters))` will produce a number `n` where `0 <= n < Len(letters)`. In most languages this is what you want, but in VBA `Mid` requires `1 <= n <= Len(letters)`. So just add 1. I will update the answer.